# force ISE synthesis tool to synthesize a signal

Tags: fpga, xilinx-ise

In Xilinx ISE (using VHDL language), I have defined these signals:

```
signal  counter  : integer range 0 to 24_000_000;
signal  chTriger : std_logic :='0';
```

and have written the following code:

```
process_counter: process(clk)
begin 
  if ( clk'event and clk = '1') then
    if (counter < 8192) then
        counter  <= counter + 1;
        chTriger <= not chTriger;
    end if;
  end if;
end process process_counter;`
```

In ChipScope's select net menu, there is neither a `counter` nor `chTriger` signal due to optimization.
How can I force ISE synthesis tool to synthesize a signal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read through the Xilinx constraints guide [here](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx14_4/cgd.pdf) 
especially the synthesis constraints. 
There is one which is called "KEEP".

In general it is a very useful document to browse if only so you have an idea what you can (and can't do).

Comment: a perfect answer for my problem : 

https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Synthesis/How-to-avoid-signal-optimizing-in-synthesis/td-p/76056

Comment: You should also set "keep hierarchy" to `soft` or `rebuilt` in the synthesis options..

Answer (score 0):

Output `chTriger` to an external pin on the FPGA. Then it can't be optimized away.

And since `chTriger` depends on `counter`, then `counter` won't be optimized away either.

Comment: i did that, but not trigger happened in the Chip-scope! besides i want to implement many signal in Chip scope and it is not applicable to define each of them as output.

Comment: putting pins that are needed for debugging to an output is a bad idea. In many cases you wont have enough pins - that' why we use ChipScope instead of a real logic analyzer. It has a huge impact on the timing of the signal.

Comment: It's not clear from the question that this is a debug only signal - the entire `counter` was being optimized away meaning that its output is not currently connected to anything meaningful yet - that would also have a huge impact on timing. If whatever `counter` is going to be driving isn't yet implemented then it can be useful to temporarily drive a testpoint instead - that may or may not be useful in this case but there isn't enough information to judge that. (And if properly constrained, any timing issues should show up in the static timing analysis).

Comment: (just to be clear - I do agree with the accepted answer)